# what is wrong with this wordpress update query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

all

I am using wordpress update query function.

my code is

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'on')
{
  $form_id = $_GET['form'];
  $entry_id = $_GET['id'];
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query(
  "
  UPDATE $wpdb->wp_frm_items 
  SET alerts = 1
  WHERE id = $entry_id     
  "
  );
}
```

So what i want to do is if i get action as **on** then i want to update `wp_frm_items` table alerts field as 1 which row id is `$entry_id` . 
This is not working for me, what is wrong here ?

Comment: there no problem with the script i think it updated table did you check it

Comment: Yes checked twice, let me do it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_frm_items SET alerts = 1 WHERE id = $entry_id" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

(source:[Wordpress update mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936448/wordpress-update-mysql-table/)
)

**Example:**

change user's  Nicename and ID

```
$execut= $GLOBALS['wpdb']->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_nicename = %d WHERE ID = %s",        "Sample_Nicename ", 546 ) );
var_dump($execut);
```

Learn more at:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples