# In PHP how do I rename a string in one function and use the result in a second function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Pardon me if this is ultrabasic, I'm fairly green to all this.

I'm trying to fetch a string value (chapter name) from a wordpress database, use a php function to rename the value and then concatenate the renamed value with some other variables to create a member_id.

Below is my current code (added to **functions.php** file) and I have 2 problems with it:

1. From the 1st function, when I use the shortcode `[member_chapter]` in a page/post I always get `PG` no matter what value of chapter name was used to register. If I switch the order of the **foreach** statements, then I always get `BB`, i.e. I always get the return value of the first `if` statement no matter what chapter name is actually in the database.
2. From the 2nd function I never get the chapter_id, instead the result is always like `FAL--2020-1007`, i.e. it doesn't add the chapter_id value generated from the 1st function

I'd really appreciate any help.

```
/**
 * Fetch chapter name and return as 2-character chapter_id 
 * Create shortcode for viewing chapter_id 
 */
add_action('user_register', 'fetch_chapter');
function fetch_chapter(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = \'chapter_name\' AND user_id = ' . $current_user->ID);
    foreach($result as $row){
        if ($row->meta_value = 'Peregrine') {
            return $row->meta_value = 'PG';
        }elseif ($row->meta_value = 'Barbary') {
            return $row->meta_value = 'BB';
        }else { 
            return $row->meta_value;
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('member_chapter', 'fetch_chapter'); 

/**
 * Generate unique_id
 * Retrieve chapter_id
 * Create member_id
 * Add member_id to user_meta table
 */
add_action('user_register', 'generate_member_id');
function generate_member_id($user_id){
    $unique_id = 1000 + $user_id;
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter();
    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . date("Y") . "-" . $unique_id;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'member_id', $member_id);
}
```

**Revised snippet**

```
add_action('user_register', 'fetch_chapter');
function fetch_chapter(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = \'chapter_name\' AND user_id = '. $current_user->ID .' LIMIT 1');
    if ($result[0]->meta_value == 'Peregrine') {
           $result[0]->meta_value = 'PG';
    }elseif ($result[0]->meta_value == 'Barbary') {
           $result[0]->meta_value = 'BB';
    } 
     return $result[0]->meta_value;
}

add_action('user_register', 'generate_member_id');
function generate_member_id($user_id){
    $unique_id = 1000 + get_current_user_id();
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter();
    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . date("Y") . "-" . $unique_id;
    return $member_id;
}

add_shortcode('member_id', 'generate_member_id');
```

Comment: `$row->meta_value = 'Peregrine'` is an assignment not a comparison! Use `$row->meta_value == 'Peregrine'` instead.

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code? What dou you mean by "rename a string"?

Comment: @majidhajibaba comment is useful, but note you should really be doing a full comparison `===` as Best Practise `;-)`

Comment: I suggest it in the answer @Martin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes! Please read more about program languages before writing programs. See [PHP Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/DEFAULT.asp)

In first function you used assignment operator (which is `=`) instead of comparison operator (which is `==` or `===`). You must change it everywhere use `if` in your code. Furthermore, You use return function inside *foreach*. it means your *foreach* loop runs just once and then return. You must use just if instead of *foreach* and use **Limit 1** in your sql. Or do whatever to do in your loop and avoid to `else return blahblah`. Your second problem related to your first because it probably `$row->meta_value` is null for your first record returned.

Comment: I replaced the assignment operators with comparisons. And the 1st issue seems to be fixed now. I'm still a bit stumped on how to resolve the second issue. There's now just one return statement at the end, removed foreach and added LIMIT 1 to the query, but I've definitely gotten it wrong because the returned value is just ARRAY.

Comment: You must use $result[0] instead of $row. And check in if statement whether result has any member or not.

Comment: Thanks @majidh, please see the revised snippet in my original post.

I get the correct 2-character meta_value even with additional elseif statements. But the second problem persists - the result of the 1st function isn't added to the 2nd function

Comment: You missed the `return` keyword! No need to thanks. Just upvote and accept if your problem resolved.

Comment: I just don't see it @majidh. I have the return statement in place `return $result[0]->meta_value;`. The returned value gets to the frontend (with shortcode) but not to the 2nd function.

Comment: What if meta_value not equal to PG or BB?? Try to print your result value by `var_dump(result)` too what you recieved from database.

Comment: Those are the only 2 values in the DB. I simplified it just to first get things working.

After some additional tinkering see the revised code snippet @majidh.
With `add_shortcode('member_id', 'generate_member_id'); ` I now see the correct member_id in the frontend. But how to add that value to the user_meta table in the database?

Comment: I didn't understand! If member_id is correct means your function returns right value? What you need to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, the right value is returned now @majidh, that's why I marked the question as answered. But I had to remove `update_user_meta($user_id, 'member_id', $member_id);` from the function. That means I don't have member_id value stored in my database, only displayed in frontend. How do I store the value to my database?

Comment: You can simply use `insert into..` or `update .. set ...` like as your select. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936483/2527458